# Using fluidRow with a conditional statement

Tags: r, shiny

The following app generates a dynamic UI based on the number of variables selected. A problem is that when the number of variables selected is odd, the app generates an extra UI that is not tied to any of the variables previously selected. I've tried include if statements within the fluidRow creation statement, essentially checking if there is a remainder and if so, I've tried to tell the app to insert a blank space, but this doesn't do the trick. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix the issue?

```
## libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "var",
                 label = "vars:",
                 choices = colnames(mtcars),
                 multiple = TRUE),
  uiOutput("dynUI")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dynUI <- renderUI({
    row_idx <- length(input$var) %>% seq_len
    row_idx <- row_idx[row_idx %% 2 == 1]
    row_idx %>% 
      map(~fluidRow(column(width = 2, 
                           selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("var", .x), 
                                          label = paste(input$var[.x], "var:"),
                                          choices = c("this", "that"),
                                          multiple = FALSE)),
                    column(width = 2,
                           selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("var", .x + 1), 
                                          label = paste(input$var[.x + 1], "var:"),
                                          choices = c("this", "that"),
                                          multiple = FALSE))))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect the odd variable using `is.na(input$var[.x + 1])` then span it on 4 columns as in :

```
row_idx %>%
  map( ~ {
    if (!is.na(input$var[.x + 1]))
      fluidRow(column(
        width = 2,
        selectizeInput(
          inputId = paste0("var", .x),
          label = paste(input$var[.x], "var:"),
          choices = c("this", "that"),
          multiple = FALSE
        )
      ),
      column(
        width = 2,
        selectizeInput(
          inputId = paste0("var", .x + 1),
          label = paste(input$var[.x + 1], "var:"),
          choices = c("this", "that"),
          multiple = FALSE
        )
      ))
    else
      fluidRow(column(
        width = 4,
        selectizeInput(
          inputId = paste0("var", .x),
          label = paste(input$var[.x], "var:"),
          choices = c("this", "that"),
          multiple = FALSE
        )
      ))
  })
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Hey Hubert - one follow-up question to your very helpful answer. Do you know if there is any way to modify that code so that the dynamicUI selector retains its value as 'vars' are added and removed? 

For example, if 'that' is selected for 'mpg var', then removing a variable from 'vars' multi-select results in 'map var' defaulting back to 'this'. I know based on reading Hadley's Mastering Shiny book that this is accomplished using isolate, but I can't figure out the correct implementation.

Comment: Hi @DJC, I'd store the selected value in a data.frame, evrytime it changes, and use it as first choice when re created. If you need more help, please post a new question and reference it in a comment here.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like the following?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

column2 = function(x, input) {
  column(
    width = 2,
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = paste0("var", x), 
      label = paste(input$var[x], "var:"),
      choices = c("this", "that"),
      multiple = FALSE
    )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "var",
              label = "vars:",
              choices = colnames(mtcars),
              multiple = TRUE),
  uiOutput("dynUI")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$dynUI <- renderUI({
    row_idx <- length(input$var) %>% seq_len
    row_idx <- split(row_idx, (seq(row_idx) - 1) %/% 2)
    map(row_idx, function(x, input) fluidRow(map(x, column2, input = input)), input = input)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

EDIT:

[image]